# add selected li to an existing ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements `li`

```
<ol class="selectable" id="firstList">
    <li class="ui-widget-content"> text 1</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content"> text 2</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content"> text 3</li>
</ol>
```

I want when I select one or more element in  int the first list, these selected elements should be added to another list `<ol>`

```
<ol class="selectable" id="result">

</ol>
```

Comment: jquery `click`, `clone()` and `append()`

Comment: and what have you done so faR?

Comment: what do you meant by select?

Comment: select an element li  (for example text1)

Answer (score 4):

Simply you can do something like this

```js
$('#firstList li').click(function() {
// click event handler for listening click event
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  // toggling selected class class
  $('#result').html($('#firstList .selected').clone())
  // updating result list with selected list item ( li which have selected class )
  // use `.removeClass('selected')` if you want to remove selected class from clone
})
```

```css
#firstList .selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="selectable" id="firstList">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">text 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">text 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">text 3</li>
</ol>
<ol class="selectable" id="result">
</ol>
```